# run a powershell script as a task in VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to run a powershell script as a task when doing the release in VSTS. The script runs perfectly if I run it form the powershell IDE, but I can't configure the script to run as a task in the parameter script path. I'm using  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/vs-releasenotes.ps1 but it does not work
The script is top level in the folder solution. How can I access the ps1 scritp if it is localted at solution level (no folder for the script)

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Or is the Windows Task not running. Need some more details on this case to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, I was running the script during the release phase but did not add the ps1 file to the task that copied all the files to the build directory, so it was not available. I just added the file and everything works ok